# Neo4j can not query by label following restore

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have restored my dev neo4j database from a production backup for the first time.

When I do a normal query by label which should return data:

```
match (p:Person) return p;
```

I get no data back.

If I do a simple:

```
match (p) return p;
```

I get a whole heap of data.
And if I find a specific record that I know exists:

```
match (p) where p.firstName = 'Joe' and p.surname = 'Bloggs' return p, labels(p);
```

I not only get the node I'm after back, but labels(p) returns ["Person"].

Any ideas why adding a label for my node is not working?